# L9110H-bridge motor driver

Tags: arduino-uno

So I have this old RC car which doesn't seem to connect to the joystick very well so im going to modify it with an Uno with 433 MHz receiver/transmitter.

Both the steer and drive motors work as intended so long as you can reverse their current. I've seen people use the dual channel drivers which is what I know I probably what I should use to drive the motors. I bought a starter kit a while back which came with a single L9110H Chip. I thought maybe I could order another one and just solder them to a PCB and mount the PCB along with the Uno inside the car that way I don't have an extra chip just collecting dust. I've looked at the [data sheet for the L9110H](https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf) and came up with a diagram on Fritzing.

[image: L9110H-bridge motor driver Fritzing diagram]

I was hoping someone could tell me if I'm on the right track with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, looks good to me. That looks to be identical to the "Application Circuit" on page 2 of the datasheet you link to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently trying find out if the motor is too much amperage for the chip I sent the circuit through a multimeter in amperage mode to the motor with it set to 200m and it read 1.36 not to sure if that's 1.36A or  136mA as I do have the lead(red wire) in the 10A plug on the meter

Comment: The results are probably meaningless. Measure the resistance of the motor winding.

Comment: Well I took a chance and hooked it up and got it working on the back tires gave the steer tires a go since they seem to work on the same principal and they work but there was a sound from the chip so I unplugged it right away haha

Comment: @GeraldLeese What kind of a noise?

Comment: kind of almost sounds like a buzzer beep.

Comment: I’m just testing it using a digitalwrite(pin1,HIGH) with a analogWrite(pin2, 100) maybe changing analogWrite to digitalWrite(pin2, LOW) will stop the beep. Still have to figure out PWM and speed control

Comment: Ahh so I started using analogWrite(pin1,  100) and digitalWrite(pin2, LOW) to control the speed the sound I believe is when the pwm is set too low because I when I set it below 50 on the drive motor it starts producing the sound right out of the motor